# Streaming OGG Flac to Icecast with libshout

Tags: c, ogg, shoutcast, icecast, flac

I have a simple streamer developed in C++ using LibFlac and LibShout to stream to Icecast server.
The flac Encoder is created in the following way:

```
  m_encoder = FLAC__stream_encoder_new();
  FLAC__stream_encoder_set_channels(m_encoder, 2);
  FLAC__stream_encoder_set_ogg_serial_number(m_encoder, rand());
  FLAC__stream_encoder_set_bits_per_sample(m_encoder, 16);
  FLAC__stream_encoder_set_sample_rate(m_encoder, in_samplerate);
  FLAC__stream_encoder_init_ogg_stream(m_encoder, NULL, writeByteArray, NULL, NULL, NULL, this);
```

The function `writeByteArray` sends encoded data to Icecast using `shout_send_raw` function from libshout.
`shout_send_raw` returns an actual number of bytes being sent, so I assume that it works as it should, no error is happening.
The problem is Icecast server does not stream the data that I send. I see followint in the log:

`[2018-02-15  15:31:47] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/radio" total_bytes_read (20735897)
[2018-02-15  15:31:47] DBUG stats/modify_node_event update "/radio" total_bytes_sent (0)`

I see that Icecast receives the data, but it does not send it to connected clients. The mount point is `radio` and when I try to connect to that mount using any media player - it does nothing, no playback.
So my question is how is that possible that Icecast receives the data but does not send it to connected clients? 
Maybe some additional libshout configuration is required, here is how I configure it:

`shout_set_format( m_ShoutData, SHOUT_FORMAT_OGG_AUDIO );
shout_set_mime( m_ShoutData, "application/ogg" );`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FLAC is higher bitrate than the usual streams, did you increase the queue length for that mountpoint or global? There are several fault conditions where Icecast won't send data to clients. Not receiving proper headers is one, the other is not being able to fit a whole logic chunk of data in the queue.

Comment: Do you mean the `<queue-size>` config parameter? Tried to set `<queue-size>102400</queue-size>`, it did not help.

Comment: Try a larger value. Don't forget to restart the Icecast server after changing the configuration.

Comment: I had to play with that parameter more and now it works good, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up the solution from the comments:

FLAC has a very significantly higher bitrate than any other commonly used audio codec. Thus the default settings will *NOT* work. The queue size *must* be increased significantly so that complete data frames will fit in it, otherwise, Icecast will not sync on the stream and refuse to data out to clients.

The same obviously applies to streaming video. The queue size must be adjusted either for the appropriate mountpoints or globally.